# how to save pixijs content as image

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, drawing2d

Let's say I have a pixijs app like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/o3qfi

I need to save the contents rendered by pixijs in the canvas as a screenshot.

I tried accessing the canvas like

```
app.renderer.view.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0)
```

and also through

```
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL("image/png", 1.0)
```

However both of them returns an empty transparent image, instead of the canvas content rendered by pixijs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to `extract` it from the `renderer`.

For example, if you want to print the `stage`:

```js
let blob = app.renderer.plugins.extract.image(app.stage).src;
window.location.href = blob.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

Will download the following image:
[image]